# How to convert LaTeX to PDF/PNG by PHP

Tags: php, pdf, latex, pdflatex

I have `LaTeX` code inside PHP (not as .tex file); for example received by $_POST. How can I save the rendered `LaTeX` as a PNG or PDF file on my server?

**EDIT:** I know that PHP normally does not do this. I will run a shell command within PHP. Thus, I need something to do so in Linux terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could exec() pdfTex to generate a PDF

URL: http://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex/

Run command

```
pdftex file.tex
```

after you saved your tex-code from $_POST to a file using file_put_contents() - make sure you have the rights to write in the specified folder.

hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I am currently doing this. I hoped to find a way to do this within PHP.

Comment: @Ali: There is no PHP-implementation of LaTeX.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Thanks, I know. I will execute shell command within PHP (I just wanted to introduce my environment). In fact, I am looking for a Linux command to do so.